# Where should I create methods to use in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Sorry for the newbie question, but I often wonder.
Where should I create methods that I want to use in my View??

I'll illustrate.
I want to call a method in my user/views/show.html.erb that will return a boolean and with that I can show a link on the ***show*** page, or not.

Well, I'll always thought that this method should be created at the User.rb, the model!
But what I actually get is an undefined method error!

I would apreciate the help!

Thanks

**UPDATE**

It does work when I create the method in the **User Helper**..
But is that *good* programming? Is it the *right* way? Or is there a *better* way?

Comment: You should probably show us the relevant part of the User model.

Comment: It's just a dummy method that returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually guys, it's pretty simple
The newbie here didn't call its user method using the object:
example: @user.my_metho
I was just calling my_method

That was the problem.

But as Pedro mentioned the Draper gem really didn't do much for me...
Couldn't even get it to work properly...

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays I prefer to use a presenter, similar to what is [shown in this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper). It keeps your code clean, reusable, and is more close to OO than Rails Helpers, which keeps you more sane. :)

Comment: do you use draper?
Because I installed the gem but the g draper:decorator command wouldn't work. It can't find this specific generator.

Comment: Did you add it to your `Gemfile`? It should AFAICT.

Comment: What's AFAICT?
Yeah, it is in my Gemfile and i couldn't generate because it has a diferent syntax than the onw used in the railscast.
But in the decorator I get a NoMethodError when I call a helper method. even using 'h.' before the mehtod name to specify that is a helper method...

Answer (score 0):

I think that if its display-related code, it should probably go into the specific helper, or in 'application_helper' if you want it available in all views. Formatting and display logic (like what you have) should go into helpers.

If the method is going to make changes to your data, then it probably should go into a model. Not sure what you are getting an undefined method error, because it should work.